# Sublime text comment indentation issue with Ruby

Tags: ruby, sublimetext2, auto-indent

I use SublimeText since a few months with ruby, and I have a issue with comment auto-indentation. Indentation uses the comment's indentation, and indent all the following code using this indentation. I expect auto-indentation to ignore(at least) or set indent of previous code (at best), but not to take comment's indentation at all :

All my colleagues who use this editor have the same issue
Here's a sample code re-indented by SublimeText

```
class Test
  def method1
  end

    #Bad indentation
    def method2
      somecode
    end

    def method3
      somecode
    end

  end
```

Wanted :

```
class Test
  def method1
  end

  #Bad indentation
  def method2
    somecode
  end

  def method3
    somecode
  end

end
```

I did a quickfix on 
~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/Indentation Rules - Comments.tmPreferences

Replacing

```
<key>scope</key>
<string>comment</string>
<key>settings</key>
<dict>
    <key>preserveIndent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

With

```
<key>scope</key>
<string>comment</string>
<key>settings</key>
<dict>
    <key>preserveIndent</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
```

But it affects the default behavior, and I do prefer only affect Ruby's behavior.
Does anyone has greater solution ?

Comment: I'm really sad that no one gave you an answer to this question. I really want to know. :|

Comment: so sad, after so many years, we face the same question, but we still have no solution too......

Comment: theTuxRacer 's answer is right, beautifyruby really can fix this issue, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [BeautifyRuby](https://github.com/CraigWilliams/BeautifyRuby) ST2 package. You will also need to install the `htmlbeautifier` gem. Not only your comments, but also your code will be indented nicely.

If you use rvm, you might need to change the  `BeautifyRuby.sublime-settings` to use the ruby installed by the rvm, instead of the system installed ruby. To find out the path of ruby you are using, type `which ruby` at the shell prompt. Paste this path as the value for the key named `"ruby"` such as:

```
"ruby": "/home/thetuxracer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby"
```

and beautifyruby can be use with : edit->beautify ruby

or you can change it keybind:

```rb
    { 
  "keys": ["alt+tab"],
  "command": "beautify_ruby", 
  "context": { "key": "selector",
    "operator": "equal", 
    "operand": "source.rb, source.ruby" }

  },
{
  "keys": ["alt+tab"],
  "command": "reindent", 
  "args": {
    "single_line": false
    },
  "context": { "key": "selector",
    "operator": "not_equal", 
    "operand": "source.rb, source.ruby" }
  },
```

Comment: no use with the question: tab follow comment

Comment: sorry, my miss, beautifyruby reallly can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my User settings file:

Preferences -> Settings -- User :

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Theme - Refined/Color Schemes/Danro.tmTheme",
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
"font_size": 18.0,
"hot_exit": false,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"remember_open_files": false,
"save_on_focus_lost": true,
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

}

I tried to recreate your problem and I couldn't with these setting enforced.

Comment: no use with the question: tab follow comment

Answer (score 0):

For indentation following is the key setting

```
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
```

This works for me

```
{
"caret_style": "solid",
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",
"enable_tab_scrolling": false,
"folder_exclude_patterns":
[
    ".git",
    ".hg",
    ".sass-cache",
    "log",
    "tmp",
    "script",
    "vendor",

],
"font_size": 10,
"highlight_line": true,
"highlight_modified_tabs": true,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"rulers":
[
    100
],
"scroll_past_end": false,
"tab_size": 2,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Comment: no use with the question: tab follow comment

Answer (score -1):

For ST3,
Preferences -> Settings -- User

Add following code:
  {
    "tab_size": 2
  }

By default SublimeText uses hard-tabs that are 4 characters long.

Comment: no use with the question: tab follow comment